# Google Map edit taking long to be accepted

Tags: google-maps, edit

I have edited the address of my business on Google Maps but its taking more than a month to be reviewed and accepted. Is it the normal process? How long does Google take to accept a new Address. Any one can share their experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make changes via [Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/)?

If you use Google My Business and own the business place feature, you should be able to reach out to the Google support specialists who can help you with address update.

Have a look at the Google My Business Help Center, particularly at the page that explains how to change the address

https://support.google.com/business/answer/7005371?from=cuf

Note that at this page Google offers callbacks and chats during business hours and also you can contact them by email.

[image]

I hope this helps!